# Programmatic Constraint issues in Swift Playgrounds Program

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

wondering how to update constraints for a custom UI View. Definitely are errors in my code. I apologize in advance, I'm just a beginner at Swift.

```
public class NoteCardView:UIView {
@IBInspectable var contentView = UIButton(frame: .zero)
@IBInspectable var delegate: MainViewController?
var leftAnchor: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor
var bottomAnchor: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor

override public func updateConstraints() {

    contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    contentView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 6
    contentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 75).isActive = true
    contentView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    leftAnchor = contentView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leftAnchor, constant: positionX).isActive = true
    bottomAnchor = contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: (delegate?.view.bottomAnchor)!, constant: positionY).isActive = true
    titleLabel.textAlignment = .center
    titleLabel.text = note
    contentView.addSubview(titleLabel)


    super.updateConstraints()
}

class MainViewController: UIViewController {
override func viewDidLoad() {
// Trying to implement updated constraints to the NoteCardView here.
}
}
```

Also having this other issue that is unrelated with the TapGestureRecognizer. I'm not very familiar with this concept either.

```
public class NoteCard:UIView {
internal var titleLabelTapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer?

internal func commonInit() {
self.titleLabelTapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTitleLabelTap(UITapGestureRecognizer)))
}

internal func handleTitleLabelTap(_ recognizer:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    self.delegate?.noteCardViewTitleLabelDidRecieveTap(self)
}
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: If nothing else, your left anchor is between content view and itself, which doesn't make sense. Also, you generally need to add a view to the hierarchy before setting any constraints. If you get constraints based error messages, please share the precise messages (after you fix the aforementioned constraint).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues in your code :

1. What Rob mentioned in his comment :
   `contentView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leftAnchor,
   constant: positionX)` - this doesn't make sense, as constraints
   should be between anchors of two different views. Also constraints should be configured after adding views to hierarchy.
2. Also with the same line : `leftAnchor = contentView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leftAnchor,
   constant: positionX).isActive = true`. This line has actually two
   problems :

   2a. This compound assignment evaluates to this :

   ```
   contentView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leftAnchor, constant: positionX).isActive = true
   leftAnchor = true
   ```

   Which means, that you try to assign `true` to a variable of type `NSLayoutXAxisAnchor`. Same applies to `bottomAnchor`

   2b. As to the type of `leftAnchor` - it should be `NSLayoutConstraint`, because calling `constraint` on an anchor creates a `NSLayoutConstraint`. If you wanted to grab a reference to an anchor, you would simply call `leftAnchor = contentView.leftAnchor`.
3. You setup not only your constraints, but your whole view in overridden `updateConstraints` method. While this isn't wrong, I would advise against it with such simple views. I'd rather make a `public func setup()` method and call it from view controllers `viewDidLoad` to setup the view and its constraints.
4. As to the gesture recognizer - you also need to add it to a view, it's not enough to initialize it. Simple `self.addGestureRecognizer(self.titleLabelGestureRecognizer)` should do the trick.